# Ansible playbook parameter from dynamic inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Given the following playbook, I would like to assign specific hostnames to every member of the hostgroup.  Therefore, the `name` parameter needs to change for every instance in the hostgroup.

```
- name: friendly hostname
  hostname: name=clusterXmember.1
```

How do I access the machine names from the inventory file?  Specifically the current machine's ip, or the hostname?

As the playbook runs, I'd like the `name` param to be pre-filled with data from inventory. (generated from *terraform*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I access the machine names from the inventory file? Specifically the current machine's ip, or the hostname?

The inventory name is accessible in different formats via the [built-in variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts) `inventory_hostname`, `inventory_hostname_short`, and `ansible_hostname`.  See the documentation I linked to for a description of each.

The IP can be obtained via the [facts that are gathered](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts) for each host.  You will probably want to use `ansible_default_ipv4['address']` to get what you are looking for.